# Delete multiple rows with checkbox and PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

How can I delete multiple rows with checkbox and PDO prepared statements?

With given code, I can delete only last one row from checkded rows, but not all them. I think I have mistake in **Main.php**, concretly in prepared statements.

How can I solve this problem?

**Main.php**

```
       // DELETE DATA with PDO
       public function delete($id){
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE id IN (:id)";
        $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        return $stmt->execute();
    }
```

**index.php**

```
    // DELETE DATA
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      if ($user->delete($id)){
        echo "Data Deleted Successfully.. </br>"; 
      }
    }
```

*form* in **index.php**

```
<form method="POST"> 
<div class="row">
   <?php if ($user->readAll() > 0) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($user->readAll() as $value) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 ajax-del"> <!--Delete div with AJAX--> 
      <div class="card border-secondary mb-4">
          <a href="#"><img src="<?= $value['image'] ?>" alt="<?= $value['name']?>" class="card-img-top img-fluid"></a>
          <div class="card-body bg-light text-center">
            <input type="checkbox"  class="float-left" value="<?php echo $value['id']?>" name="id"></<input>
            <p class="card-text mt-3"><?=$value['barcode'] ?></p>
            <h5 class="card-title text-danger font-weight-bold"><?= $value['name']?></h5>
            <p class="card-text">$<?= number_format($value['price'], 2)?></p>
            <p class="card-text"><?=$value['weight']?></p>
            <p class="card-text"><?=$value['size']?></p>
            <p class="card-text mb-4"><?=$value['height']?> <?=$value['width'] ?><?=$value['length']?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   <?php endforeach ?>
   <?php endif ?>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger float-right mr-3" id="delete" name="delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: The function only takes one ID, so it doesn't look like it would be able to delete multiple rows unless you called it multiple times. I guess `$_POST['id']` is the checkbox value? Is it an array or a single value? I assume it's a single value if the function works at all, but maybe it's not supposed to be. What does your form look like?

Comment: I have updeted and pasted `form` code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple form controls with the same name, PHP will only get the last one, because the name attribute becomes an array key in `$_POST`, and array keys are distinct by definition. So `name="id"` in your checkbox means that PHP will only get the last one. You can define the name so that it will be accessible an array in `$_POST` using square brackets. Change it to `name="id[]"`.

Then you'll either need to modify your function so that it takes an array or call it multiple times with each id in the array.

If it was my project I would prefer to modify the the function to take an array.

```
public function delete(array $ids) {
    $placeholders = trim(str_repeat('?,', count($ids)), ',');
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $this->table WHERE id IN ($placeholders)";
    $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
    return $stmt->execute($ids);
}
```

If you don't change the function, you'll just need to call it multiple times.

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id) {
        if ($user->delete($id)) {
            echo "Data Deleted Successfully for $id.. </br>"; 
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: It's working.. problem solved.. thank you very much.. You helped me get started my first Work in company..

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with your work.